# Unable to convert QString to WChar Array

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

```
QString processName = "test.exe";
QString::toWCharArray(processName);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: C2664: 'QString::toWCharArray' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QString' to 'wchar_t *'
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Comment: It's usually easier to just use processName.utf16()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using it incorrectly. You should be calling `toWCharArray` on the `QString` you want to convert and passing it a pointer to the first element of an array you have allocated:

```
wchar_t array[9];
QString processName = "test.exe";
processName.toWCharArray(array);
```

This fills `array` with the contents of `processName`.

Comment: array[9] = 0; // should be added, as array[9] may contain gibberish.

Comment: ... which will create a buffer overflow since array[8] will be the last valid element. Since toWCharArray returns the length of the string, it would probably be better to capture that and set the null byte accordingly.

Comment: The `toWCharArray` method doesn't add a null terminator, so the last line should be `array[processName.toWCharArray(array)] = L'\0';`.

Comment: Also in general there is no easy way to know in advance how much memory you need to allocate (in this example, what do you do if the length is greater than 9?). `toWCharArray` returns the length of the wchar array, but you need to allocate the memory for the wchar array before you call `toWCharArray`. Also if the length of the wchar array is fixed (in this case 9) there's no way to specify a maximum length to `toWCharArray`.

Answer (score 11):

I found the current answer is not enough, 'array' may contain unknown characters because no zero termination to 'array'.

I had this bug in my app and spent a long time to figure it out.

A better way should be looking like this:

```
QString processName = "test.exe";
wchar_t *array = new wchar_t[processName.length() + 1];
processName.toWCharArray(array);
array[processName.length()] = 0;

// Now 'array' is ready to use
... ...

// then delete in destructor
delete[] array;
```

Comment: He does say "of an array you have allocated".

Answer (score 7):

1 line neat solution:

```
processName.toStdWString().c_str()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the answer from Jake W.
He is using the method toWCharArray. Unfortunately this method doesn't terminate the string and that is why it didn't work in my case.
This one worked perfect:

```
QString processName = "test.exe";
(wchar_t*)processName.utf16();
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include "QtCore/QVector"
// ...

QVector<wchar_t> wcharVector(myQString.size() + 1);

myQString.toWCharArray(wcharVector.data());

wcharVector[myQString.size()] = 0;

// Now wcharVector.data() is wchar_t*
```

Comment: This is already covered by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361091/466862)

Comment: No, it's not. Here I use RAII. In the answer by the link RAII is not used. And I personally needed it with RAII.

Comment: Then I recommend you add some explanation to your answer instead of posting only code.